# Integrating Git-Tower and Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, git-tower

I am attempting to use Git-Tower with Gerrit with and am having difficulty having Git-Tower set and recognise the proper push refspec.

In our workflow we have two remotes: `origin`, pointed at a github repository; and `review`, pointed at our Gerrit code review machine.  I have verified that pushing to Gerrit works from the command line with:

```
git push review HEAD:refs/for/develop
```

In Git-Tower I configure the push refspec to `refs/heads/develop:refs/for/develop` and have verified in the git config file that this has been set.  However, when I try to push from within Git-Tower to `review/develop` Git-Tower attempts to push to `refs/heads/develop` rather than `refs/for/develop`, and since I am not an administrator it fails (as it should).

How should I configure either Git itself or Git-Tower specifically so I can use this workflow from within Git-Tower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After configuring the Push Refspec (as you already did), you shouldn't need to make any more customizations: when clicking "Push", you can leave the setting to "origin/"!

If this doesn't work out, you can get in touch with our support crew via support[at]git-tower.com.

Comment: I managed to get something working with this answer.  I removed my second `review` remote and put all the configuration within `origin`; I changed the push URL to point at Gerrit and the push refspec as mentioned above.  Then when I pushed with `origin/<default>` selected from the branch drop-down I was able to push to `refs/for/develop`.  Is there anyway to make `origin/<default>` the default selection in the drop down?  Leaving it on `origin/develop` pushes to `refs/heads/develop` in Gerrit instead of `refs/for/develop` and it is somewhat cumbersome to change it each time I push.

Comment: I contacted @Tobidobi by mail for that question and that is his answer:
> At the moment, Tower cannot preselect the "origin/<default>" item since the preselection mechanism in Tower is based on Git's "tracking" relationships (and Gerrit choses not to use this).
However, although I can't make any promises, I'll make sure this gets noted on our list of feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove tracking from the master branch (right click the branch in the sidebar and choose "remove tracking"), that will allow the push refspec to preselect the gerrit branch. That way you don't have to switch branches after hitting push.